# Positioning Bubbles with forced intersections in Jquery

Tags: jquery, intersection

I've got Categories and Subcategories. Subcategories can belong to one or a maximum of two Categories.

Now I need to generate Bubbles for each Categorie and if a Subcategorie belongs to two Categories those two Bubbles need to intersect. (See Image) I don't have a good Idea on how to do it and was hoping some of you might have an clue.

[image]

Maybe there's also a Plugin that could help me with that?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this doesn't allow me to force intersections by subcategoies... or not as far as I can see.

Comment: http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/bubble/fertility_rate_life_expectancy/

Comment: Again, using a BubbleChart doesn't let me chose the Intersections by Subcategories. I apologize since I just realised I put "BubbleChart" into the title, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can adapt those plugins, just check the docs for each one and choose accordingly

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks :)